# How do I get the path of a typescript file, and not the compiled javascript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

My goal is to get the correct path for a typescript file, and not the compiled js files. I have `tsconfig` configured with output to a dist folder, so my structure look like this:

- src

  - sample.ts
- dist

  - sample.js

My current code uses the `__filename` variable, but it points to `dist/sample.js`. How can I get the path of the typescript file, i.e. `src/sample.ts`?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not exactly sure what problem you're trying to solve, but if you know the `/src` and `/dist` structure and `__dirname` points to the `dist` folder, you should be able to do this:

```
let srcPath = path.join(__dirname, "../src");
```

to get to that directory.

If you need to open a file in that directory, then add that filename onto the end of that:

```
let srcFilename = path.join(__dirname, "../src", someFilename);
```

Comment: I think you understand the problem well, because `path.join(__dirname, "../src")` would solve the problem. Only problem is that the question is using a simplified setup of my project, and I don't want to count how deep I should go, i.e. `../../../../../../../../src`. So that's why I am asking if there is a way, where I can get the typescript files path, and not the compiled js.

Comment: @DauleDK - Hmmm, I don't have TypeScript installed to research it further.  I think the debugger somehow knows how to get access to the original source files if things are configured properly.  So, it's apparently doable.  But, not something I know.

Comment: @DauleDK - What is the real problem you're trying to solve?  If you're just trying to get access to some resource that is back in that `src` directory, then you should probably modify your build script so that it puts that resource in a directory that is a simple path from the `dist` directory `__dirname` (below it, or at the same level do you can get their with a simple `../resources` reference from `__dirname`.